# Is there any way to have private data?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm aware of shortcut links. Looking for behavior similar to that of a native Google doc. File exists, possibly takes up storage, can be renamed/moved/deleted, but the data inside shouldn't be modified except by the app. Possibly, defining export formats/links.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is a simple "no" - Google Drive is for storing user files, not protected application data or configuration data. So you could put a file to a users drive, but only the owner of the drive can control whether the file is shared or changed. So they can edit it, you can't stop them, and there's no reason to think that'll ever be a feature in the future.

To have such control you will need to store such data on your own server, or some other such storage medium.

The only other thing that you would do with only Google Drive is encrypt the configuration file you store, for instance, so it couldn't be easily edited - but that's probably just a bad idea. If you must save a configuration file to a persons drive, bury it inside an application folder and sanity check it to ensure it isn't corrupt - but don't count on a person or application never opening and editing it. If it's something a person shouldn't be able to read or change, don't save it to their drive.

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2012, application data is supported: [What is the Application Data folder?](https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata).

"Export format links" could be done with [Custom file properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/properties), though, I'm unsure of what kind datatypes are supported for the value beyond the example string.